# How can I search for a keyword in unanswered questions?

Tags: support, search, tag-search

Can I search for a keyword or a tag, but only see the questions which have no answers?

If not, I want this as a feature request :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `answers:0`. This will limit your search to only questions with no answers.

So, if you wanted to search for the word "flarble" in questions tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) with no answers, you'd search `flarble [c#] answers:0`.

Comment: Pretty sure all questions including the word *flarble* will have zero answers....

Comment: Thanks ! But what if I don't want to search for a word, but just with tag? Will `[c#] answers:0` work?

Comment: @halilpazarlama Try it and see? ;) (hint: yes)